# Running webmin under lighttpd

Tags: linux, lighttpd, webmin

According to this: http://www.webmin.com/apache.html it's possible to run webmin under apache. Would it be possible to do the same under `lighttpd` and how can it be achieved? The reason why I want to use `lighttpd` instead of the inbuilt webmin webserver `miniserv.pl` is because I'm running a low memory embedded device.